# Issue in displaying Jenkins build data to influxDB

Tags: jenkins

I am facing some issues in fetching Jenkins build data into influxDB. Actually, the main requirement in automated testing services is to show Jenkins job data on Grafana dashboard. So, I have created a Jenkins job and also added influxDB plugin for the same with all configuration changes made as per steps provided in [Visualize Jenkins build data through InfluxDB in Grafana](http://christoph-burmeister.eu/?p=2887https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116711/how-to-install-influxdb-in-windows). [Query was already raised to author of URL but did not received any updates till now. That's why I posted my query here]

The only change I did is that I have created a sample Windows batch command instead of Shell command (as I am using a Windows 7 machine). Further, the database is shown in Grafana dashboard. But since the Jenkins job data is not shown in influxDB so its not shown in Grafana dashboard as well.

Please let me know in case some step is not included in URL provided above so that Jenkins build data can be shown in influxDB.

Comment: You may get better results asking this in Stack Exchange or by contacting the author of the URL.

Comment: Hi @KatePaulk I have raised this query to author of URL but did not received any updates till now. That's why I posted my query here. Thanks!.